# Ошибка: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 27, 48)

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

Tensorflow 2.0. Обучаю на своем датасете.

Код создания модели:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(27, 48, 1)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Код распознавания

```
img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_file, target_size=(27, 48, 1), grayscale=True)
img_arr = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
result = model.predict_classes([img_arr])
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(27, 48)))
...
```

---

```
img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_file, target_size=(27, 48), color_mode="grayscale")
img_arr = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
result = model.predict_classes(img_arr)
```